# c# npoi excel How to get a cell's formula VALUE?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I set a formula on some cells in a loop like this:

```
System.String fm = "IF(B2,J2=J1,FALSE)"
another.GetRow(0).CreateCell(28).SetCellFormula(fm);
```

I always wondered how to get the result (value) of this formula and not copy the entire formula.

```
MessageBox.Show(another.GetRow(0).GetCell(28).ToString);
```

it displays value `IF(B2,J2=J1,FALSE)`

how can get the result (value), not the formula itself?

Answer (score 9):

```
HSSFFormulaEvaluator formula = new HSSFFormulaEvaluator(workBook);
```

then you can use this formula for all cells in your excel file by using

```
formula.EvaluateAll();
```

or you can use it for specific cell like this

```
var cell = sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(column);
            string Res = "";
if (cell != null)
            {
                formula.EvaluateInCell(cell);

                switch (cell.CellType)
                {
                    case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Numeric:
                        Res = sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(column).NumericCellValue.ToString();
                        break;
                    case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.String:
                        Res = sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(column).StringCellValue;
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
another.GetRow(0).GetCell(28).NumericCellValue;
```

You can use several different properties based on column type.

Comment: cannot work, it display value 0,but in excel dispaly FALSE

Comment: So try to use BooleanCellValue property

Answer (score 3):

You can set the cell type to a string, it worked for me as its getting the calculated value:

```
ICell cell = sheet.GetRow(i).GetCell(1);
cell.SetCellType(NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.String);
var value  = sheet.GetRow(i).Cells[1].StringCellValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  "EvaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook)" method to evaluate all formulas after setting it into excel file. see this link [How to re-calculate a cell's formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088737/how-to-re-calculate-a-cells-formula)

Answer (score 2):

Use **StringCellValue** to get the value from cell your formula will not read

```
MessageBox.Show(another.GetRow(0).GetCell(28).StringCellValue
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html

example

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
```